# Open external program using URI Scheme without creating new tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, opera-extension

I want to pass url to external program (open url with program), but without creating new tab/window. I used "chrome.contextMenus.create" to open url with program: right-click the link & "open with external program": http://postimg.org/image/usj1yb8gj/

I wrote next code for my chrome-extension:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        title: 'Open with some program',
        id: 'nameOfprogram',
        contexts: ['link'],
    });
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId === "nameOfprogram") {

        //var win = window.open("NameOfUriScheme://" + info.linkUrl, '_blank'); // '_self' - doesn't work...

        chrome.tabs.create({ url: "NameOfUriScheme://" + info.linkUrl },function(tab){setTimeout(function(){chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);}, 1000);});
        }
});
```

But it opens new tab for 1 second to open url. 
Can be **uri-scheme:adress** (when uri associated with specific program) open **without** creating new tab when you opens it using **contexts menu**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omg.  I just need to replace `create` to `update` - `chrome.tabs.update({...});`